# Do we really need to use </body> and </html> closing tags?

Tags: html

More often than not I see HTML without the closing tags, especially `body` and `html`.

According to:

> http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-body-element
>
> http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics.html#the-html-element

This can be omitted, but what about cross device issues? Like running such HTML on **androids** or **windows phone's** or whatever you know where not having these closing tags this would not work.

Comment: Why do you care about 7 or 14 bytes more or less? This won't make any difference at all, so just close the elements and you're fine.

Comment: It is not about the size. It is more about - does it work everywhere as expected. Let's imagine that half of my team add's closing tags and the other half does not. So, I am not sure how it has to be for sure so that it works everywhere as expected.

Comment: In HTML, they are optional. That is, the official standard says you can leave them out. And I don't know of a single browser that has problems with them being omitted. Or in other words, if a browser _would_ have problems, that would be a serious bug, and such a browser would not be allowed to be deployed!

Comment: That said, it's always good practice to put those end tags in, yadda yadda yadda.

Comment: So, `<!DOCTYPE html><head><title>wtf</title></head><h1>hello</h1>` is a completely valid HTML file?

Comment: @CedricReichenbach Yes, `<!DOCTYPE html><title>wtf</title><h1>hello</h1>` without the head is also perfectly valid. Your browser may, however, wrap and head and body as it sees fit. Check it out in dev tools.

Comment: You don't need to put full stops (periods) at the end of your sentences for them to be understood It's not clear what advantage you might derive from leaving them out Nevertheless it's pretty clear that full stops are a technical formality rather than a necessity

Comment: @Rounin Your comment is about a different language than HTML, and therefore off topic. But let me ask you something. Do you write `<tbody>` in all tables that you create?

Comment: My comment was about formal language conventions in general, not about any specific language - and therefore on topic. As to your question, my answer is no. But in those tables where I do write <tbody>, I also write </tbody>. Closing elements is a standard convention of HTML for non-self-closing elements. Is an extended discussion about this really helpful? Do we "need" to close <html> & <body> elements? No. Should we (nevertheless) generally conform to this standard language convention? Of course. I'm sure we are very much in agreement on this specific question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do we need it? Well that depends on your DTD. If you're using XHTML, then yes, you will need it to conform. For accessibility sake I would include the closing tags, you never know if there's a screen reader (or other piece of software) out there that only parses valid XHTML, you could be hindering partially sighted people for example.

Google will also, apparently, rank your valid documents higher than invalid documents in their listings.

[Here's a document](http://www.leemunroe.com/how-important-is-valid-html-web-standards/) by a friend of a friend that answers your question a bit better; granted that it was written in 2008, I think some of the points still apply.

If you ever need to use the same html in an XHTML application you won't need to mess around with it, you can just copy it across and not have to worry about conforming (because you already are).

On a separate note, you are essentially future proofing your markup. Who's to say that the spec won't eventually change to "You must include the closing head and body tags"? You won't need to worry if you already have them. It is, however, highly unlikely that the spec will change to, "You must **not** include the closing head and body tags".

---

As a great man once said:

> Should I close the lid of the toilet when I'm finished? Yes,
>   especially if the wife is going to use it after me.
>   - Darren Gourley (Nov 2015)

Comment: Anyway, whether you need all end tags or not does not really depend on the DTD. It depends on the filetype. A `.html`file with an XHTML doctype declaration on top is still HTML. On the other hand, an `.xhtml` file with a HTML doctype declaration is still XHTML and still needs all XHTML decorations such as the `xmlns`.

Comment: @MrLister hah! I've update the answer. Hopefully there's no confusion now.

Comment: @MrLister I'm fairly confident that the file extension doesn't matter, it's the Content-Type header that determines the media type the content should be interpreted with if served over http.

Comment: I could have said MIME type instead of file type, if that would have made it clearer. But the same is true for the local filesystem, where you don't get a server in between that assigns a Content-Type header.

Comment: It would have. Typically MIME types are mapped to the Content-Type header for statically requested files over http. These, however, can be changed on the server depending on your needs. You could sent .htm files out with a content type of "application/xhtml+xml" if you really wanted. If the request is coming through your application you can also define your own MIME types for certain extensions and override what the server has. I think we can sum up by saying that MIME, Content-Type and DTD all play a part in this bigger picture.

Comment: Anyway, if it _is_ compatibility with XHTML that you want, remember that writing all end tags explicitly is only part of the work. Use lowercase element names, quote all attribute values, give all boolean attributes their proper values, include the xmlns namespace, use id in addition to name where appropriate, put `<tbody>` start and end tags in every `<table>`, avoid `&` and `<` in scripts, never use `document.write` or `<noscript>`, forget about entity references other than the five XML ones, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

use https://validator.w3.org/

select your standards target... if that says it passes then I think its Gd enough.

Please bared in mind the HTML5 spec is still being defined/evolved.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you could omit html, head and body tags all together as long as the markup follows the following conditions:

http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/syntax.html#optional-tags

In regards to your comment about half your team using them and half your team not I would suggest that as long as either option is technically standards compliant you just choose one and move on as the entire subject is open for discussion and interpretation. My personal opinion would be that it's probably more important for your team to get on the same page and produce work of a similar standard especially if you have more than one person working on a project simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

You can leave out the end tags. Indeed you can leave out the opening tags, too (obviously not if you are using any attributes on them).

Not only is that the case with the more recent standard, but it's been the case since the very beginning. (The obvious exception being if you are using the XML syntax, since XML itself requires all elements have an explicit closing tag.)

Browsers have been dealing with the existence of HTML documents lacking the trailing closing tags since the 1990s. If the standards hadn't allowed it they'd probably still have dealt with them, much as they try their best to deal with all manner of messy code. (This causes it's own problems, which was one of the motivations behind XML not allowing optional tags, but that's another matter).

Many people consider it poor style. I would be one of them. But it's certainly widely supported.